# Matlab: Boxplot with individual value markers

Tags: matlab

How can I produce boxplots that also show all the values by themselves?
e.g. like here in subfigure A and B of this:

[image: pic]

I can just plot them after a "hold on" but then they are not nicely arranged according to the x-axis as in the example above. Isn't there a matlab standard function for that?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? I'm not sure what do you mean by "show all the values by themselves" but you should look into subplot function, I can give you an exemple if it suits your needs.

Comment: I would use the awesome [notBoxPlot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26508-notboxplot) function from the FileExchange by Rob Campbell. Easy to use and very nice output

Comment: The "notBoxPlot" does that in principle but the distribution along the x-axis seems random and not nicely arranged like in the example above

Comment: well I guess you could look into the source code and play with the arrangement of individual markers